# CSV file load without cursors

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, cursor

I need to read a CSV file and loop thru all the records and perform some cleaning up of data for few fields and insert them to 3 different tables a,b and c.
I don't want cursors, please suggest me a simple but faster way to do this. TSQL code snippets will be helpful.

Comment: Why do think you need a cursor and what precisely is your difficulty? You can just load the file into a table with bcp.exe or `BULK INSERT`, then clean the data using whatever `UPDATE` statements you like and finally `INSERT` into the three tables.

Comment: This might help: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/02/06/sql-server-import-csv-file-into-sql-server-using-bulk-insert-load-comma-delimited-file-into-sql-server/

Comment: Why do you need cursors? Can you load the data to temp tables and do the cleanup using WHERE clauses, then load the cleaned up data to permanent tables? Or just load the data to the permanent tables and do the clean up?

Comment: This is called ETL. Extract the data into the buffer, Transform (do cleanup) in the buffer, Load (insert into table(s)).

Comment: Along with what @Pondlife said, you might want to import into a temporary table, then do the cleanup/inserts so users don't see/use the data in your live table.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using SSIS (SQL Server Integration Services)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx

Or if you are on an older version of SQL (SQL 2000), you can use DTS:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc707786(v=sql.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc707786%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

This will allow you to import the CSV file, do data cleanup, and insert the data where you want based on your own criteria.